# Calling a Joomla Module to php file

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How to call a joomla module by id to a php file. This Php file is inside a directory in root folder like test/test.php

```
$modules =&  JModuleHelper::getModules('155');

foreach ($modules as $module){
    echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm i think there are 2(3) modes/method.

1. In your PHP you have to integrate all joomla parts (framework) and than call your PHP
2. I more propher way is to use extensions ([click - list of them](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content)) which will give a place to code your staff in addition to Joomla!
3. The best will be to a develop a module/plugin/component. But that could take some time.

So the best solution for you is a think a 2. one becouse you will end up with a custom PHP file but in a addition will be Joomla framework features.